# Возможно ли сделать окантовку фразы (не букв) средствами css/js?

Tags: html, css

[image: Пример]
Называется "Вокруг формы"

Comment: Что из себя представляют эти формы? Добавьте код html в ваш вопрос

Comment: <p>Какой то текст</p>

Comment: попробуйте многослойный css text-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="dilate" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha" radius="2" result="e1" />
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha" radius="4.5" result="e2" />
    <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor" result="outline" />
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline" values="1 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 0 0 0                     0 0 1 0 0 
        0 0 0 .8 0" result="outline2"/>
    <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="over" result="output"/>
  </filter>
    <text id="group" filter="url(#dilate)" y="40" x="15" fill="violet" font-size="40px" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
      <tspan x="15" dy="2">UNREAL</tspan> <tspan x="45" dy="31">NEON</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Могу предложить вот такой вариант с svg-текстом. Возможно, не точь в точь, как Вы хотели, но всё же. Окантовка здесь у всего слова целиком (но с очертанием букв), а не у каждой буквы отдельно + определенное расположение слов даёт эффект такой как бы общей (для двух слов) окантовки.